# Can I use ASCII characters (specifically char(10)) when concatenating text fields in Power Query?

Tags: powerquery, m

My CRM system requires address lines before town/city to be imported into a single field, with separate lines (where there are more than one) separated by the delimiter char(10).  I need to import a file which has two columns for this data, so I need to merge the columns into one.

This is what I've tried in Power Query

```
[address line 1]&char(10)&[address line 2]
```

However, I then get an error message saying "The name 'char' wasn't recognised.  Make sure it's spelt properly".

Any ideas?  I feel like this is the opposite of what most people want to do in Power Query, which is separate out text strings...  I actually want to squeeze it into one column!

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out - see below (I can't mark my answer as correct for another 2 days).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, no sooner had I posted than I figured it out!  The correct answer is

```
[address line 1]&Character.FromNumber(10)&[address line 2]
```

Edited to add: the below is better - the above code will only work if both fields are populated.

```
if [Address Line 2] is null
then
[Address Line 1]
else
[Address Line 1]&Character.FromNumber(10)&[Address Line 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have your answer, just thought I'd add another way of doing it.

```
...Text.Combine({[address line 1], [address line 2]}, Character.FromNumber(10))...
```

It's a bit more flexible as you can add as many fields between the `{` and `}`. Also, I think `Character.FromNumber(10)` can be written as `"#(lf)"`, so above could also be written as:

```
...Text.Combine({[address line 1], [address line 2]}, "#(lf)")...
```

Or you could use `Table.CombineColumns`. So something like:

```
Table.CombineColumns(someTable, {"address line 1", "address line 2"}, Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("#(lf)"), "Combined")
```